# How can i find pathname of a file in macosx without moving to the specific directory where the file is located?

Tags: macos, unix, path, homebrew

i want to go to specific file without searching for it by going in to all the directories and typing ls and all i know the file name and i want its path with just filename.Please help im new to unix programming and im interested in learning it thoroughly.And i have homebrew and iTerm (zsh) installed.Thank you.

Comment: Don't understand how you expect to find the path without searching for file if all you know is the filename.  The only way to get path is to either search or go to the parent folder using finder. But if you can go to parent folder you must already know path.

Comment: Type 'locate filename' into a terminal window. This should list the file and its full path.  If it lists nothing, you may have to move up a directory or two by typing cd .. and then repeating the locate command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want find an executable file in your PATH you can use the `which` command:

```
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

If you want to find a file by name then you can use the `find` command. For example, to find a file called `sample.txt` somewhere in your current directory or any subdirectories:

```
$ find . -name sample.txt
./sample.txt
./temp/sample.txt
```

In the above example, `find` found two files called `sample.txt`

You can use wildcards in the name (remember to put the name in quotes, eg. `'*.txt'`) and there are many other options to narrow your search. For more info in the `find` command:

```
$ man find
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you see the file in a `Finder` window, and want to get to that directory without having to type out a long `cd` command.

You can drag and drop a file or folder from a `Finder` window into a `Terminal.app` window:  this will cause the `/path/to/file.name` to be printed out at the cursor's position.

So if I wanted to list the files of a folder on my desktop in a terminal window, I would first type `ls -l` in the terminal, and then drag the folder into the `Terminal.app` window.

```
[nevin-mac-mini:~/Desktop] nevin% ls -l /Users/nevin/Desktop/Eclipse 
total 584
-rw-r--r--@ 1 nevin  staff  126127 21 Aug 15:32 DSC_7956 (1).jpg
-rw-r--r--@ 1 nevin  staff   95940 21 Aug 15:50 DSC_7960.jpg
-rw-r--r--@ 1 nevin  staff   71307 24 Aug 08:42 DSC_8025.jpg
drwxr-xr-x  5 nevin  staff     170 23 Aug 18:19 publish
[nevin-mac-mini:~/Desktop] nevin%
```

The folder name `/Users/nevin/Desktop/Eclipse` was automatically entered when I dragged and dropped the folder icon from my Desktop onto my `Terminal.app` window.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called 'Go2Shell'. This app places an icon on your finder window that when clicked, will take you to the same directory in a terminal or iTerm window. So if you display the directory with your file in a finder window, clicking the Go2Shell icon will open a terminal window to that directory.

If you just want the path to the file you can right click on file and hold down the option key. One of the options is to copy the path to the selected file.

Another option is to type 'locate filename' in the terminal. It will list the full path of file assuming it finds it.